# Laravel - Select top chained table row

Tags: laravel

Lets say I have chained tables like this:

```
lessons -> sections -> courses
```

(courses table is top of this chain)

These tables connected to each other by a key which is an id:

```
lessons.section_id = sections.id
sections.course_id = courses.id
```

(lessons table have no direct link with courses table)

Now how can I select related courses table row for example in update method of lessons controller? Is this right?

```
$lesson = Lesson::find( $id );
$course = DB::table( 'lessons' )
    ->join( 'sections', 'lessons.section_id', '=', 'sections.id' )
    ->where( 'sections.id', $lesson->section_id )
    ->join( 'courses', 'sections.course_id', '=', 'courses.id' )
    ->first();
```

Or is there any better way?

Comment: Use [Model relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Still not using Models and Relationships eh? Would be quite easy; would just call `Lesson::with(["sections" => function($query) use($lesson){ $query->where("id", "=", $lesson->section_id"; }), "sections.courses"])->where("id", "=", "id")->first();`

Comment: Thanks guys. Why I didn't a little search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Relation like this

Lesson Model

```
public function getCourseAttribute()
{
    return $this->section->course;
}

public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
}
```

Section Model

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

And Your controller like this :

```
$lesson = Lesson::find( $id );
$course = $lesson->course;
```